# What is the meaning of "I make this appointment"?

Tags: grammar, usage

When we call a doctor's office, we say,

> I want to make an appointment.

However, I saw another use of this expression. It was like this:

> I'm very busy. I make this appointment only since I take it this is urgent for you.

What is the meaning of this expression? Does it mean "I am answering (or am present for) this appointment only since..."?

Comment: In general, it's a good idea to provide a source whenever possible. Are you sure it didn't say "**I'll** make this appointment"?

Answer (score 1):

The doctor would say this to confirm an appointment with you and to give a reason for giving you an appointment.

To break it down

> I make this appointment
>   *I am giving you an appointment with me*
>   *I am making an appointment with you*
>
> only since
>   *only because*
>
> I take it
>   *it is my understanding that*
>
> this is urgent for you.
>   *this is urgent for you.*